# How do I index values in a multiple data type array in Lua?

Tags: arrays, lua, coordinates, null

This is a strange question but it baffles me. I want to be able to store x and y co-ords on an id based system such as: id.1.x = 10, id.1.y = 15: id.2.x = 50, id.2.y = 42 and I am trying to make a function to do it for me, I am having issues. here's my code

```
a = { p = {x,y}}
function box(xpos,ypos,id)
a[id].x = xpos
a[id].y = ypos
end
box(25,30,1)
box(45,10,2)
print(a[1].x.." "..a[1].y)
print(a[2].x.." "..a[2].y)
```

which I wanted to print:

```
25 30
45 10
```

but instead I get the error:

```
attempt to index global '?' (a nil value)
```

I am really exhausted and would like to put this to rest so if somebody could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function box(xpos,ypos,id)
  a[id] = {x = xpos, y = ypos}
end
```